# Screen flickering - Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, screen

I recently installed Lubuntu 20.04. on a HP 15-db0021ng Notebook.

For a few months everything went well. Then suddenly the screen started flickering. The first two times after a reboot the flickering was gone for several weeks. Then it came back. Today it's persistent for the first time, even after multiple reboots.

The screen simply glitches every second or so.

Any help would be great, many thanks in advance!

Comment: If it was related to a kernel upgrade (*drivers* are technically kernel modules, thus upgrades to kernels are significant) the issue won't occur if an older kernel is used (one before you noticing it). You can boot older kernels at grub (use the Advanced option & select an older kernel). From your description I'd also check it wasn't the machine misbehaving because of a knock or other, and test it using different software (ie. boot *live* media such as installation media, but I'd opt to test using a number of different OSes, if the issue occurs there with all of what you test - it's hardware)

Comment: By different *live* OSes I'd test your Lubuntu install media for example (it'll be an older version of the stack you're currently using), but also other *live* systems that are non-Ubuntu as a means of testing hardware.  If the first test (trying older kernels selected at grub advanced..) then it's a *regression* that should be reported with `ubuntu-bug linux` at terminal (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and as for support options; if you're using the HWE stack, I'd switch to GA stack as a fix. If you're using the GA stack, I'd try HWE etc.  Alas I don't know what you're using

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!